# Java. Socket. Array. Передать массив строк через сокет

Tags: java, массивы, сокет

Мне нужно передать через сокет массив строк, я хотел использовать для этого `ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream` но столкнулся с тем что идея зачеркнула мне `ObjectInputStream` как устаревший и опасный класс.

И у меня возник вопрос: а какая существует альтернатива `ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream` не считая `Byte/ByteArrayInput/OutputStream` для передачи объектов?

ps. по байтам не хочу...

Буду очень признателен если подскажите.

Comment: Эм, как это deprecated, 8u102 полет нормальный. Используйте эту реализацию

Comment: Вы что-то путаете, `java.io.ObjectInputStream` не является устаревшим.

Comment: Видимо это баг у меня в IDEA я просто хотел убедиться что не только я  так думаю. Спасибо.